# Google-drive-sdk-samples, how to fetch with SVN

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the .Net samples for connecting to Google drive, but how do you get em with SVN? I can not find the url for SVN.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not hosted on svn, but Mercurial. From the [source page](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/checkout):

> Get a local copy of the google-drive-sdk-samples repository with this command:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/
```

Comment: So I need to install Mercurial?

Comment: @Jacob: Looks like it. Personally I like TortoiseHG (http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) and VisualHG (http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)